# Converting this type color value to ARGB

Tags: c#

If I inputted 0xffffffff then the output must be: 
A: 255
R: 255
G: 255
B: 255

I can't find any tutorials for converthing this. Thanks!

Comment: show what you did.
post the code in the description.

Comment: I still didn't do anything because I don't know the formula for converting that. Can you tell what kind of color value is this? "0xaa336539"

Comment: Use a calculator and you'll see that hex `0xaa` converts to decimal `170`, `0x33`= `51`, etc..

Comment: I don't get it. sorry :\. I don't have any background in this type of color.

Comment: Does saying "Alpha Red Green Blue" provide enough background  for you to google it?

Comment: I mean, don't have background for converting this type of color.

Comment: Basically you have 32 bits of information defining four 8-bit color channels, and you want to extract each channel

Comment: Thanks for extra info! I really appreciated it! :D

Comment: Changing your example 32bit value to 0xffffffff just made your question more confusing.  You should restore the old example, then add your new one if you want. @ChrisDunaway gave you a .NET answer.  Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Color` structure ( From the .NET `System.Drawing` assembly) to parse this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

void Main()
{
    var c = Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)0xaa336539));
    Console.WriteLine("Alpha: {0}", c.A);
    Console.WriteLine("Red: {0}", c.R);
    Console.WriteLine("Green: {0}", c.G);
    Console.WriteLine("Blue: {0}", c.B);
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
Alpha: 170
Red: 51
Green: 101
Blue: 57
```

Answer (score 2):

shifting and masking.

(although some prefer using a `/ 256` for the shift and a `% 256` for the mask )

```
unsigned long x = 0xaa336539;

// Note the LSB to MSB order

//mask
unsigned char b = x & 0xff;

//shift
x >>= 8;

//mask
unsigned char g = x & 0xff;

//shift
x >>= 8;

//mask
unsigned char r = x & 0xff;

//shift
x >>= 8;

//mask
unsigned char a = x & 0xff;

// Technically, just saving it into an 8 bit wide container is the same as the masking, although some compilers might warn you
```

Comment: You can also just use:  `var c = Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)0xaa336539));` and then just access the R, G, B and A properties.

Comment: It probably is better to use that .NET method that @ChrisDunway recommends, instead of rolling-your-own like I did (but maybe mine helps show the origin of things).  If he makes it an answer, you should move the check mark to him  Reference URL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hmm,  the C# tag went away...  maybe its not a .NET thing anymore

Answer (score 1):

```
// Original input
var input = "0xaa336539";

// Gets aa336539
var inputRemovePrefix = input.Substring(2);

// Converts to a long
var numberConversion = long.Parse(inputRemovePrefix, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

// Converts to 6 character hex string so the next operation will always work
var convertedInput = numberConversion.ToString("X6");

var aVal = int.Parse(convertedInput.Substring(0,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var rVal = int.Parse(convertedInput.Substring(2,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var gVal = int.Parse(convertedInput.Substring(4,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var bVal = int.Parse(convertedInput.Substring(6,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

// Prints result
Console.WriteLine($"A: {aVal} R: {rVal} G: {gVal} B: {bVal}");
```